# How can I find the resonating frequency of a piezo crystal?

Tags: frequency, ultrasound, piezo, piezoelectricity

The crystal looks like in the given image I want to find the resonating frequency, whether is it variable or fixed.

1. I find its manufacturer has not given much detail about it.
2. Does a piezo resonate on a variable frequency or will it resonate on fixed frequency only?

[image: Piezo Crystal Chip]

Comment: Please add a link to the manufacturer and ideally, a link to the data sheet.

Comment: From the picture in the question, could be [Low-Voltage Piezoelectric Chips with Through Holes, 1.8 µm to 3.0 µm Travel](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=10311) from Thorlabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the transducer as the tuned element in a ["crystal" oscillator](https://www.apogeeweb.net/article/147.html) with no other resonant circuit. Check the output with an oscilloscope or frequency counter. A one-transistor [Pierce oscillator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sinusoidal_oscillators/sinusoidal_crystal_oscillators.htm) or [Colpitts oscillator](https://eepower.com/technical-articles/introduction-to-quartz-crystal-oscillators/) should work.

You can also check the resonant frequency *in situ* that way, since placing the transducer in a cavity can shift the frequency, or make it prefer harmonics or subharmonics.

For that matter, use the oscillator to drive the device in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing this is an audio frequency piezo transducer?  Since it appears to have a distinct polarity it may incorporate an oscillator and will buzz if a DC voltage is applied (although there’s no clue what the correct voltage is, could be anything from 1.2 to 24V or above or below.  If it’s just a transducer then it will sound to some degree with an applied waveform but will be much louder around its resonant frequency, so testing experimentally with a signal generator would be the way to go.

Comment: An"ultrasonic transducer" likely will not be louder -- unless one has a friendly bat or dolphin handy.