# Do piezoelectric or piezoceramic sensors have a fixed resonating frequency?

Tags: frequency, ultrasound, piezo, piezoelectricity, piezoelectric-effect

I am working with a sensor which has piezos in it. I want to know what piezo resonating frequency really means. The piezo I'm using has a resonating frequency of 570kHz as mentioned on the website.

What does 570khz really mean? Does it work only on 5tokHz or is 570khz the threshold limit of the piezo sensor? What should be the operating voltage of piezo? They haven't mentioned anything related to it.

Manufacturer number of the piezo sensor: PKCEP4  2.0 mm x 2.0 mm x 0.4 mm flat end plate

[Product](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=PKCEP4)

[This datasheet link](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=8040&pn=PKCEP4) is on the above page

[image: Piezo Sensor]

Comment: Monesh Rathod - I see you have now added [this link](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=PKDEP4). However that is not the link to the piezo sensor. Please check & add the correct link for the sensor you are asking about, not just for some end plates. TY

Comment: Monesh Rathod - I see you have made yet another edit and removed the original image. However you are still *not* linking to the datasheet of the *sensor* as you claim. You are linking to the product page for some very small "end plates". Your text in the question even says "PKCEP4 2.0 mm x 2.0 mm x 0.4 mm flat end plate". That is *not* the sensor. So your question is confusing & unclear :( You are asking about a *sensor* but you are linking to the product page for something which is *not the sensor*. || As I said before: Please check & add the correct link for the sensor you are asking about.

Comment: Monesh Rathod - Your other recent question [How to find resonating frequency of Piezo crystal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/695731/101063) contained a picture of what look like [Low-Voltage Piezoelectric Chips with Through Holes, 1.8 µm to 3.0 µm Travel](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=10311) from Thorlabs. Is this question about the same sensor, or a different one?

Comment: Please confirm that data sheet link that I have added as the correct one for your product.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - Re: "data sheet link that I have added" - The [link you added](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=8040&pn=PKCEP4) doesn't go to a datasheet, but to the product page for many different piezo stacks, each with their own datasheets. But none (that I could find on that page) have a resonant frequency of 570 kHz to match that stated by the OP. Which one did you find on that page matches the OP's specs? TY

Comment: @SamGibson I was on my phone. I saw none that matched. I "hoped" that the OP would follow through and check as per my comment. If not the current progress towards closure will probably continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web site you cited gives this description of how to operate a piezoelectric device:

`In general, PZTs are usually operated well below their resonant frequency (fo), particularly when used as a precision positioner. The reason for this is to keep the phase difference between the applied voltage and the PZT's displacement as low as possible. A piezo system is typically run anywhere between DC and >10 kHz.`

This and additional information on how to operate these devices is on this part of their web site:

https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=5030

The manufacturer did not provide any details on the resonant frequency for the particular device you asked about.  However, they do provide the below plot for a different piezoelectric device with flat end plates:

[image]

[image]

This does show that for this particular device the resonant frequency falls off roughly exponentially as the applied load increases.

Unfortunately, I could find no similar plot for your device.  In view of the advice quoted above, you should operate your device well below the resonant frequency, allowing for it to be lower as the load gets higher.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: A note, that's not an exponential curve; it's plotted semilog for whatever reason, which might be a bit misleading.  Looking at some spot values, it seems Fo ~ sqrt(load), which makes sense: this is simply describing the free resonant frequency of a load (note, not a tensile load like gramforce, a literal mass in g) attached to a spring of given rate, and hence Fo = 1 / (2 pi sqrt(m/k)).

Comment: Thanks for noting that mischaracterization.

Answer (score 1):

The natural frequency (also known as resonant frequency) of the sensor is the frequency at which it can oscillate at its highest amplitude. If you apply an external force of a given energy, you will get the highest amplitude vibration if you do so at its natural frequency. This phenomenon is know as resonance.

Piezoelectric sensors generate charge differences (thus voltage) when a mechanical stress is applied to them (or viceversa). Therefore you can understand the resonance frequency as the frequency at which the sensor will transform mechanical energy into voltage difference more efficiently, since the vibration amplitude of the system will be the highest (because of resonance phenomenon) and the voltage produced directly depends on it.

Keep in mind that this is bidirectional. If you excite your sensor at 570KHz AC, you will get the highest vibrating amplitude of the sensor. In fact, this is how ultrasound generators work.

To sum-up, 570KHz is the frequency at which you will have the best response, but technically you can work at a different frequency. Despite that, I would recommend you to stick to the resonant frequency whenever possible.